# Samsung Series 5 NP510R5E-S01CA battery issue

Tags: battery

I was using my laptop one day and it was plugged in but it suddenly stopped charging. It didn't say "Charger connected, not charging" or anything. It was like the cord wasn't even plugged in.

I checked the power cord to make sure everything was plugged in and after that didn't work I tried a different outlet which also didn't work, by now my laptop is at 4% and I had tried using another cord that fits my laptop and still no charge!

It's been 9 days now and it hasn't turned on or showed any signs of life. I even tried the battery reset button located on the bottom of the laptop but nothing happened. It's just suddenly stopped charging! The cords & charger port are not damaged either!

Does anyone know what is happening or what caused this? I just need to know because I'm going to buy a new one if this one is toasted.